# Pentaho kettle join streams with different fields

Tags: merge, stream, pentaho, transformation, kettle

I have multiple steps in my transformation where i join data from different streams (files). All streams have a common field which is ID_Time.

Now when i try to join 2 streams on ID_Time, lets say using Multiway Merge Join, I get fields ID_Time and ID_Time_1. I'd like to merge those into one, so we get rid of the _1 column. If we do not have the same columns in both streams, I would like the ones that we do not have to be null.

An example:

```
ID     Number1 Number2  ID_Time 
 1      5,06     215     12154
 2      5121     121      151


  ID    CarModel CarManufacturer ID_Time
  1       CX3         Mazda        12
  2       V40         Volvo        39
```

So i would like this as the end result:

```
ID Number1 Number2 CarModel CarManufacturer ID_Time
 1   5,06    215     null         null       12154
 2   5121    121     null         null        151
 3   null    null    CX3         Mazda        12
 4   null    null    V40         Volvo        39
```

Maybe I have to use a different join? Or on different keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of both `Merge join` and `Multiway Merge join` will always include all fields from all streams; if fields are repeated they will be suffixed with `_1`, `_2`, etc.

One obvious case is when the join keys have the same name (which if often the case), but you may also have other fields with the same name.

There are several ways to go about it, but the easiest would be a `Select values` step after the join, and remove the duplicated fields (one of the tabs of Select Values is called "Remove", it will remove any fields you specify).

Your final Id field can be added after the merge, with a `Add sequence` step.

**Beware**: always sort the inputs before joining, as both merge steps assume the input data to be sorted.

Comment: I've noticed that the result is not as expected after the merge - first stream of the join has values at `ID_Time ` and `null` at `ID_Time_1`, and the second stream has `null` at `ID_Time` and values at `ID_Time_1` in the result. I'd like all the values to be under `ID_Time`. So if i remove the duplicates, I will also remove some `ID_Time` values. And yes, the streams are sorted ascending on the join key.

Any idea how to merge the duplicates under the same field? Like replace null ID_Time value with value of ID_Time_1?

Comment: Ah, you’re absolutely right. in that case you can use a Calculator step, and use the NVL operation to keep the one not null key value before the select values step.

Comment: The Calculator step with the NVL operation did the job! Thank you very much :)